# Trying to display custom value in cell using mRender returns an error using Datatables

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datatables

I am using datatables in angularjs to display list of products in a Table.
By using **mData** I am able to bind values to the columns, But when experimenting with **mRender** it is returning an error.

```
      <table ui-jq="dataTable" ui-options="{
      sAjaxSource: 'http://www.server.netshell:3001/product/getMyProductsList', 
      aoColumns: [
        { mData: null,sDefaultContent: '' },
        { mData: 'productname' },
        { mData: 'published' },
        { mData: 'condition' },
        { mData: 'type' },
        { mData: 'category' },
        { mData: 'price'},
        { mData: null, sDefaultContent: ''},
        { mRender: function(data, type, val){
            return data.productID;
        }}

      ]
    }" class="table table-striped b-t b-b" id="pTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th  style="width:20%">Product ID</th>
        <th  style="width:20%">Product Name</th>
        <th  style="width:25%">Status</th>
        <th  style="width:25%">Condition</th>
        <th  style="width:15%">Type</th>
        <th  style="width:15%">Category</th>
        <th  style="width:15%">Price</th>
        <th  style="width:15%">Added</th>
        <th  style="width:15%">Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Here, I am trying to fetch **ProductId** and send that ID to my controller for **Edit** or **Delete** onclick. But when trying to display simple **productId** in that column it returned an error

[image]

Looks like syntax error but couldnot find where i am missing it!

Can someone help me with this?
**Reference**:
[Datatables mData](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns)

Answer (score 0):

1. The error you get comes from AngularJS parsing the `ui-options` property. I am not sure but the double `}` after the `mRender` could be a problem, try inserting a space or linebreak there.
2. According to the reference you gave, `mRender` needs a corresponding `mData` in the same column. The `data` parameter is what you give as `mData`, the `val` parameter is the full object of the row. Check that too.